# How to update existing contact using content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to edit the contact of my phone using content provider. To load data i have used below code and it works fine.

```
private ArrayList<String>  getRecords()
{
    ArrayList<String> records=new ArrayList<String>();


    Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        String name="";
        String phone="";
        String id="";

        do{
        id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));


            name =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            phone =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


        name = id+" "+name+"\n"+phone;
            records.add(name);
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    return records;
}
```

Now i want to edit actually want to change the name of the selected contact. i am trying below code

```
Uri uri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, id);
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, "<r XX");
    getContentResolver().update(uri, values, null,null);
```

But it is not updating. What can i do know? Please help. I already check over internet as well as other ans but did not find satisfactory ans.

Answer (score 1):

you dont seem to supply the update paramaters properlly:

the method consist of:

```
getContentResolver().update(uri, values, where, selectionArgs)
```

the where should contain:

```
 "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID+"=?"
```

and the selectionArgs should contain the id of the contact to update.

Comment: Uri uri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 3625);
  ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
  values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, "Mr XX");
  getContentResolver().update(uri, values, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID+"=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(ID)});

Check this code. But it is not working :-(